# Error 406 while querying a Socrata dataset

Tags: php, socrata

I'm trying to create a site in php whereby a person can check if a business is in a list of businesses. That list is [here](https://data.southbendin.gov/Business/South-Bend-Businesses-Open-to-All-Customers/mqet-2q6r).

I'm getting "Error 406 from server", which I believe means I asked for the data in an unacceptable format. The page first presents a form for a user. They write in the businesses name which is posted to this piece of code as `$_POST["name"]`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I mostly tried to follow the example called index.php in the Socrata php library. I did implement `require(socrata.php);`

```
$view_uid = "mqet-2q6r";
$root_url = "https://data.southbendin.gov/Business/South-Bend-Businesses-Open-to-All-Customers/";
$socrata = new Socrata($root_url);

$params = array("\$query" => "SELECT * WHERE business_name = " . $_POST["name"]);

$response = $socrata->get("$view_uid", $params);
var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but not quite!

For your `$root_url`, you actually want to use the domain for South Bend's data portal, `https://data.southbendin.gov`: https://github.com/socrata/soda-php

For more details on that API, you should read its API documentation: https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.southbendin.gov/hyxr-yvey

Comment: Thanks, I'm still struggling though. I changed `$root_url` to what you suggested and now have

`$params =  array("\$where" => "business_name = " . $_POST["name"]);
        
$response = $socrata->get("resource/$view_uid.json", $params);`

But I get an error "Error, could not parse SoQL query \"select * from #mqet-2q6r where business_name=Ignite Michiana\"

I've looked through the documentation, but all the examples I could find give urls to demonstrate queries but don't show how you build them with code. I could post more code if that's helpful, but I'm about out of characters.

Comment: Put single quotes around your business name: `"business_name = '" . $_POST["name"] . "'"`